# "A stationary ball starts to move along a straight line with velocity $v=2x$." Impossible?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

In my physics assignment, there is a problem which asks me to consider the scenario where

> "A stationary ball at the origin starts to move along the $x$-axis with velocity $v=2x$."

($x$ is the displacement) And the problem goes on to ask about forces, kinetic energy, etc. But the point is, can this imaginary scenario really exist?

When I try to analyze its motion, the differential equation $x'=2x$ gives $$x=C*e^{(2t)}$$ ($C$ is a constant). With initial condition $x(0)=0$ given in the problem, the only solution is $x(t)=0$, which is certainly not true.

So, the motion described in this assignment question cannot actually happen in the physical world right?

Comment: In such questions, it is considered that at t=0, the object is given an infinitesimal displacement from its original position.

Comment: Thanks. If so, how can I obtain the x(t) function? What initial condition should I plug into the differential equation?

Comment: Write $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and then integrate. If you want to do definite integration, use x=0 initially.

Comment: Honestly this just seems to be a poorly phrased problem.